# Can I use an Arduino Uno-style Shield with the Arduino Mega, Tre, or Zero? How about the Intel Edison?

Tags: arduino-galileo

Can I use an Arduino Uno-style Shield with the Arduino Mega, Tre, or Zero? How about the Intel Edison?

Comment: Those are two different questions. Please edit one of them out of this post and create a new post with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zero, Mega and Tre all have the same basic pinout layout as Uno, which provides at least physical compatibility for the pins. [Sparkfun has a breakout board for the Intel Edison](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13097).

Mini, Micro & Nano obviously have a different pin layout. I would consider them mainly for projects that have challenging space requirements, since their main advantage is their small size. The Micro should be the easiest to plug'n'play (native USB COM serial). Nano is still stuck with FTDI drivers, so it's going to require separate drivers from the Uno/Mega family. And finally Mini doesn't have USB at all.

Maybe take a look at Wikipedia [list of Arduino boards and compatible systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Arduino_boards_and_compatible_systems) to evaluate better what suits your needs best.